Persist React native MMKV data
I am using "react-native-mmkv" to store the user details. i am using encrypted storage. Everything works fine until user kills the app, after app kill & reopen app, storage cleared, hence user is getting redirected to login page again.
I want to persist storage data until logout.

Do not initialize the MMKV instance until you have the password, then load it with the encryption key.
let mmkv: MMKV | undefined

function onLogin(user: User) {
   mmkv = new MMKV({
      id: 'encrypted',
      encryptionKey: user.password
   })
}

